# distinct date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table which has rows with the same dates ex.

```
      Date
    --------------
1/02/2012
1/02/2012
1/02/2012
```

How can i distinct them and get only one row result ex . 01/02/2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really very simple, you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Date]
FROM YourTable
```

Or:

```
SELECT [Date]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT [Date] FROM tablename GROUP BY [Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Date
FROM [TableName]
GROUP BY Date
```

Just to give a different answer.  : )

Answer (score 1):

Use: `select distinct Date from TableName`